# how to redirect calls to root URL alone to a sub path

Tags: .net, iis, web-hosting

I have hosted .net core web api as a website in iis, and added angular app as a application to the same website. [image]

my application url is "http://example.com/angularapp" ,  now if users try using the url "http://example.com/" then I want them to get redirected to "http://example.com/angularapp".
Note: My api urls are like this - "http://example.com/api/xyz" and I dont want that to be impacted.
URL Rewrite rule that I tried in local environment
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked finally, [image]

Regex $^ means "nothing", URL rewrite doesnt validate http and host names, but anything that is after the http and host names. So, In this case we expect only "Nothing". And for that case we are rewriting the app name to be appended to the URL.

Comment: technically "^$" would be better formed to match nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If not already installed, add the URL Rewrite module to IIS using the download [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Once installed, select your site in IIS and you should see "URL Rewrite" as one of the options:[image]

Open this and click "Add Rule(s)..." and add a blank Inbound rule. You can configure rewrite rules here to automatically route requests around your site. In your case, the regex pattern `^http://example.com/$` would work, however you'd probably want to look at refining/expanding your rewrite rules to account for things such as automatically redirecting to HTTPS, forcing a trailing slash etc.

Set the action to rewrite and define the Rewrite URL as the location you want matched requests to point to, in this case http://example.com/angularapp .

Note the above pattern would **only** match http://example.com/ and so your API requests would be unaffected.

Comment: It is better to use server variable HTTP_HOST to match example.com. Pattern only matches the uri part of the url that follows the domain name.

Comment: @Jimerson I tried , but it did not work. updated the screenshot above. Is there anything like if there is a port number present it wont work? and how can i create a generic rule with variables for domain and port number - as there are different environments where my web.config remains same for all.

Comment: @user1066231, Bruce's answer is correct. The pattern he has provided will work as the generic rule you want, though you may want to combine it with other rewrites to ensure it works both with the presence of a '/' on the end and without (as he highlights).

Answer (score 1):

Note: Pattern will not match http and host name. You'd better learn [how to use url rewrite module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) first of all.

I'm not sure if you know how to edit web.config so I'll show the GUI of add the correct rule.

[image]

It will redirect `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/angularapp`. BUT, if the url is `http://example.com`, it won't redirect. I'm not sure if you want to redirect `http://example.com`, so this just a remind.

Comment: your answer was helpful, but not the correct answer. as it did not work. But definitely the key take away from your answer was that "Pattern will not match http and host name". Thanks for that. I have posted the correct answer that worked and its explanation below.